# Python3 input() function: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes when given Hangul (한글) - invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, ipython, cjk

My Python program expects user input in Hangul and the following error is given:

```
      123 print("Please type Korean word")
\--\> 124 typed_word = input("\> ")
      124 print(typed_word)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte
```

Sometimes it complains about an invalid start byte, but it is very unpredictable as to when these errors occur because the same word in Hangul that caused the error during one run is often accepted and fine in the runs that follow and instead a different word causes the same issue.

This occurs when I'm running my Python program via IPython in the Visual Studio Code Terminal.

I've tried to run my code in IPython through a Mac Terminal window and the error does not occur when doing this. The program runs as expected in this case; exactly as it did when I was running it through the VSCode terminal in the past.

I have been working with this program for a couple months now (strictly through the Visual Studio Code Terminal) and it had never given me this error until now. Before, all words in Hangul were accepted by the Python3 input() function and the program ran perfectly fine. The code is also the exact same as it was before. The code should be expected to accept the Hangul input and save that string into a variable for later use in the code (what it originally did without issue).

I am working with a 2013 MacBook Pro with Big Sur Version 11.7.1

- Visual Studio Code version 1.71.1
- IPython version 8.5.0
- Python version 3.10.7

Comment: What encoding is your terminal configured to use?

Comment: The encoding that VSCode uses is the default:  UTF-8 without BOM. 

Edit: When I 'echo $LANG' in the terminal, I get en_US.UTF-8.